# latex table text in same height

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table in latex, but I'm unhappy with the result. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{ m{3cm} | m{4cm} | m{3cm} | m{4cm}}
Variable         & Bedeutung                                   & Variable          & Bedeutung                                \\ \hline \hline
intro\_season    & Zeitpunkt des ersten Auftretens (Staffel)   & dth\_time\_hrs    & Todeszeitpunkt in Stunden               \\
intro\_episode   & Zeitpunkt des ersten Auftretens (Episode)   & censor\_time\_sec & Zensierungszeitpunkt in Sekunden        \\
intro\_time\_sec & Zeitpunkt des ersten Auftretens in Sekunden & censor\_time\_hrs & Zensierungspunkt in Stunden             \\
intro\_time\_hrs & Zeitpunkt des ersten Auftretens in Stunden  & exp\_season       & Überlebenszeit in der Serie (Staffeln)  \\
dth\_season      & Todeszeitpunkt (Staffel)                    & exp\_episode      & Überlebenszeit in der Serie (Episoden)  \\
dth\_episode     & Todeszeitpunkt (Episode)                    & exp\_time\_sec    & Überlebenszeit in der Serie in Sekunden \\
dth\_time\_sec   & Todeszeitpunkt in Sekunden                  & exp\_time\_hrs    & Überlebenszeit in der Serie in Stunden                                     
\end{tabular}
\caption{Beschreibung der zeitlichen Variablen}
\end{table}
```

Now the cells of column 2 and 4 always contain 2 lines text, which is ok. But how can I make the first of these two lines having the same height as the lines in column 1 and 3?

I hope the question is understandable.

Comment: what you want is the standard p column but you are using m so getting vertically centred alignment change `m{..}` to `p{..}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's not really clear. How can two lines have the same height as one?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's it! Thank you.